# Iptables rule to allow the incoming request from only IP and reject all other ip's

Tags: iptables

Hi We have blocked entire country and but the same blocked country we need allow incoming request one particular IP form the blocked country

Comment: it would be helpful to show your current iptables output (something like `iptables -L -n`) to answer this more accurately

Comment: I voted to close this question as unclear and too broad (not specific enough). Like RobotJohnny said, you should [edit] the question to include details of how you've blocked requests from a particular country.

Answer (score 1):

iptables rules are evaluted on a serial basis. Whatever comes first, wins.

Just define the allow rule for this single IP 'before' the general block rule for that subnet.

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/423630/iptables-order-of-rules-do-i-understand-it-right

Answer (score 0):

To allow a single IP in: 
`iptables -A INPUT -s <desired IP address> -j ACCEPT`

however the functionality of this would depend on your current iptables rules.

I will update this answer accordingly should you provide your current rules set up (you can omit/replace any public IPs for privacy)